# How to exchange SAML assertion between IDP and SP

Tags: saml, federated-identity, service-provider

Here are the snippet of code for exchanging SAML assertion between IDP and SP, I can get the SAML assertion from IDP, but the code to fetch the SAML assertion from IDP in the SP's side doesn't work.

```
def exchange_assertion(self):
    """Send assertion to a SP."""
    # sp[u'sp_url'] = http://localhost/Shibboleth.sso/SAML2/ECP
    response = self.session.post(
        sp[u'sp_url'],
        headers={'Content-Type': 'application/vnd.paos+xml'},
        data=self.assertion,
        authenticated=False,
        redirect=False)

    # the status code is 302, so I assume it's okay so far.
    self._check_response(response)

    # sp[u'auth_url'] is url of which points to SP where it expects
    # the saml assertion can be fetched from the context, but 
    # it doesn't unfortunately.
    r = self._handle_http_302_ecp_redirect(self.session, response, sp[u'auth_url'],
                                           method='GET',
                                           headers={'Content-Type':
                                           'application/vnd.paos+xml'})

def _handle_http_302_ecp_redirect(self, session, response, location, method, **kwargs):
    return session.get(location, authenticated=False, **kwargs)
```

Where I am got stuck is the saml assertion cannot be get from the context['environment']. So, what's going wrong here? Thanks in the advance for any suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

ah, there is some misconfiguration under apache, the issue has been solved.

The configuration in /etc/shibboleth/shibboleth2.xml are configured to use default Application, so I must change the applicationId to 'default' under apache, the configuration looks like this,

```
<Location ~ "/this is the auth uri/">
    ShibRequestSetting requireSession 1
    AuthType shibboleth
    ShibRequestSetting applicationId default
    #ShibRequireAll On
    #ShibRequireSession On
    ShibExportAssertion Off
    Require valid-user
</Location>
```

Then it works.

Comment: This statement doesn't help anyone who has the same problem. If you have the feeling that someone could have the same question you should add some more information. Otherwise you should remove your question.